# Why is transistor gain measured in terms of current?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Why is gain of a transistor measured in terms of current ratio instead of voltage?

Signals are often measured in volts and it makes sense as potential can exist without any load.

Comment: Because transistors have a roughly constant current gain? Why do we say that UK mains power is 240V, instead of saying it's 13A?

Comment: @Allahjane: Simply because a transistor (BJT)  amplifies current and not voltage.

Comment: @Curd:  Don't you find it silly that BJTs are referred to as "transistors"?  While technically, tubes are (field effect) transistors too.

Comment: @Oskar Skog: Don't you find it silly that vacuum valves are referred to as "tubes"? While technically water pipes are tubes too? In other words: No, I don't find it silly. That's just the convention how the words are used or not used.

Comment: @Oskar Skog: As much as I know the term "transistor" is used only for semiconductor devices.

Answer (score 7):

The inherent ratio of emitter/base current is BETA. This ratio does not describe the voltage-gain ratio. BETA is important for biasing, and computing input resistance (the amount of energy demanded from the signal source), but does not set the voltage gain.

Many electronic active elements have a *transconductance*, abbreviated gm.
Multiplying [gm * output resistance] does describe the voltage-gain. This math is accurate for bipolars, FETs (MOS and J FETs), and vacuum tubes.

For bipolar devices, gm is Ie/0.026; at 26mA (0.026 amps), gm is 0.026/0.026 = 1 amp/volt. At 26 microAmps, the gm is 0.000026/0.026 = 0.001.

A bipolar biased at 26uA, with 10Kohm in the collector, will have 0.001 * 10K or voltage-gain of 10x (20dB).

To achieve controlled voltage gain, external resistors (one in collector, at least; optionally one in emitter without bypass capacitor) are used.

Maximum voltage gain for this CommonEmitter circuit is VDD / 0.026volts. Thus 9v supply / 0.026 could produce 9*39 = 350X, with challenging biasing. If collector resistor were replaced with constant current source (an PNP), your gain can rise another 10X or 100X.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnUmB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are two bipolar stages, biased identically. Left has Av = 1.0X, right has Av = 18X.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLznoT.png)</sup>

Comment: Kudos for introducing Win Hill's transistor description, as seen in his "Art of Electronics" text.  Hill tells a story of how he finally grasped transistors as a student, after having his nose rubbed in the fact that BJTs are actually voltage-input transconductance devices, Ebers-Moll and gm, same concept as FETs and vacuum tubes.  See http://cr4.globalspec.com/comment/720374/Re-Voltage-vs-Current

Comment: There was a day of epiphany at university, when GM finally sunk into my understanding. Afterward, I sat and derived voltage gains for CE, CC, CB.

Answer (score 5):

The gain for any device tends to be measured in the way that is most useful, given the physics of the device.

A bipolar transistor, because of the way it's made, happens when in common emitter configuration to have a low impedance input, and a high impedance output, and a relatively constant ratio between output and input current. Its input current is viciously dependent on input voltage, and its output current is only very weakly dependent on its output voltage. Both of those dependencies make it difficult to relate a voltage gain measured under one set of conditions to be related to another.

However, current into a low impedance, and out of a high impedance, is easy to measure, and is *useful* over a wide range of bias conditions.

Other devices tend to get specified in the best way to describe them. FETs don't have an input current, so are specified by transconductance. Opamps are high impedance in, low impedance out, so voltage gain is a natural for them.

When a BJT is used at microwave frequencies, it's difficult to measure currents, and residual impedances dominate performance, so then S-parameters are used to measure gain at the operating frequency. However, beta is still used to set up the transistor's DC operating conditions.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is gain of a transistor measured in terms of current ratio instead
>   of voltage?

Studying this graph should help: -

[image]

For a given base current (say 60 uA) it can be seen that the collector current remains fairly constant no matter what collector emitter voltage you apply. At one end of the scale with Vce at about 1 volt you get a collector current of about 11 mA and, at the other end, with Vce at 20 volts, you get a collector current of about 13 mA.

In other words, in most practical circuit examples you can say that Ic is constant at about 12 mA for a base current of 60 uA. This means the current gain can be regarded as fairly constant (in this particular example) at about 200. It'll be the same story for other base currents except there will be a small but noticeable decrease in the current gain as base current rises.

Now, if you looked at a MOSFET you would see a similar story except that the output current is determined by gate voltage: -

[image]

This is why the gain of a MOSFET is referred to as "transconductance" because you get "amps out" for "volts in" and I/V is conductance i.e. the inverse of resistance.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is gain of a transistor measured in terms of current ratio instead of voltage?

#### Answer 1

They are not.  Most transistors are roughly voltage-controlled current sources, or voltage-controlled variable resistors.

#### Answer 2

Because that's what transistors (the BJT type you are apparently referring to as "transistor") do.

A little current goes thru the base, and a lot of current is allowed to flow thru the collector.  The fact that you may think of signals as being encoded by voltage is irrelevant, and not correct for many signals anyway.

Comment: Voltage-control is how BJTs actually work inside (but that's for semiconductor class, not amplifier design.) Also, in most BJT amplifier designs, changes in hfe must be minimized, since real-world transistors have hfe which is all over the map, and hfe is not temp stable.  If hfe was important, then amplifier stages would need hand-calibrated pots, and one or two thermistors.  Typically hfe is made irrelevant by using diff-amps, cascode circuits, etc., where the BJT's input is a voltage, and any base current represents unwanted leakage.

Answer (score 0):

The BJT transistor is essentially a **current-controlled current source**. This is due to the physical properties of semiconductors arranged as they are *on this type of transistor*.

This is reflected in both the Ebers-Moll and Gummel-Poon models: The transistor gain β is a direct characteristic of BJT transistors in the linear region (usually the case for analog circuits) and is expressed as:
$$i_C = \beta i_B$$

While BJT transistors can be arranged in configurations that also include the voltage control, this usually includes some external resistors, which can be seen as current-voltage converters. As such, voltage characteristics are usually considered to be derived from current characteristics.

More information on [Wikipedia's BJT article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Voltage.2C_current.2C_and_charge_control).

Comment: Actually the Ebers-Moll model is based on Vbe, where BJTs are controlled by the potential-barrier of the emitter junction: *voltage-controlled current source.*  Gummel-Poon improves Ebers-Moll, adding "capacitor charge" of the emitter junction, since at high frequency and large currents, the actual e-fields in Emitter junction cannot be accessed at the device terminals, and must be calculated via the charge on the EB junction.  See "Art of Electronics" for multiple arguments promoting correct "voltage philosophy" of BJT input, and detailing all the design errors caused by the "hfe philosophy."